# scroll iframe onClick

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, onclick

Is there away to scroll an iframe down, left, right or up using links? e.g.

```
<a href="#" onclick="iframe down">Down</a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[googled for scrolling](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html)

Comment: Thanks wasn't what I was looking for but gave me an idea how I could do this another way :)

Comment: sorry was very specific but i'm glad it helped